# How to replace the 'When' statement to a simple ternary statement in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

1.Can I simplify the code in when statement to one or two lines.I am trying to replace the code in the when block but unable to do it.

````
// Loads all the settings changed in the theme
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        var sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            CatalystConstants.keyThemeObject,
            AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
        )

        when (sharedPreferences.getInt(CatalystConstants.prefName, CatalystConstants.themeLight)) {
            CatalystConstants.themeLight -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
            CatalystConstants.themeDark -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Are there only two different possible values for the shared preference? If not, using `if/else` is only going to be longer and more complicated.

Comment: Yes there are only 2

Answer (score 2):

If there are only two possible values, you can do this, although in my opinion `when` would be much clearer to read because the comparison is so long.

```
appCompatDelegate.defaultNightMode = if(sharedPreferences.getInt(CatalystConstants.prefName, CatalystConstants.themeLight) 
                == CatalystConstants.themeLight)
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        else // themeDark
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
```

With `when`:

```
appCompatDelegate.defaultNightMode = 
    when (sharedPreferences.getInt(CatalystConstants.prefName, CatalystConstants.themeLight)) {
            CatalystConstants.themeLight -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            CatalystConstants.themeDark -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        }
```

Could be more concise using `run`. It's not very clear, but that's because you aren't using all caps for your constant names:

```
CatalystConstants.run { 
    appCompatDelegate.defaultNightMode = 
        when (sharedPreferences.getInt(prefName, themeLight)) {
                themeLight -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
                themeDark -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
            }
}
```

Comment: Mmm.  Or a variation on the same theme: you could avoid repeating `CatalystConstants` _and_ `AppCompatDelegate` by `import`ing those constants.  — Either way, it's worth spelling out some of the saving is because you've changed the `when` from a statement to an expression,

Answer (score 0):

There is not if-else ternary expresion in Kotlin but you can write if-else statment in this way:

```
if (a > b) a else b
```

It's the most similar way to ternary if-else

Comment: In my view, Kotlin's `if` _is_ a ternary operator: `if (…) … else …` is _spelled_ different from `… ? … : …`, but it's still an operator that takes three operands (which is what ‘ternary’ means), and it has precisely the same result.

Comment: Yes, I agree but the question ask for how to convert the when expresion to the ternary expresion and in the case of Kotlin the if statement is a ternary expresion